# Getting "RuntimeError: Calculated padded input size per channel: (2). Kernel size: (10). Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size"

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have created a python code to convert hindi audio file to text.
I am using "theainerd/Wav2Vec2-large-xlsr-hindi" model for the conversion.

Below is my code:

```
from transformers import Wav2Vec2Processor, Wav2Vec2ForCTC
import soundfile
import torch

# Load model and processor
model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained("theainerd/Wav2Vec2-large-xlsr-hindi")
processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("theainerd/Wav2Vec2-large-xlsr-hindi")

# Load and prepare audio

soundfile.write("resampled_audio.wav", audio, 16000)

audio, sampling_rate = soundfile.read("resampled_audio.wav")
inputs = processor(audio, sampling_rate=sampling_rate, return_tensors="pt")

# Transcribe audio
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    predicted_ids = torch.argmax(outputs.logits, dim=-1)
    transcription = processor.batch_decode(predicted_ids)

# Print the transcribed text
print(transcription[0])
```

When I am running this code in jupyter notebook getting the error message:

**RuntimeError: Calculated padded input size per channel: (2). Kernel size: (10). Kernel size can't be greater than actual input size**

Please help me how to fix this runtime error.

Thanks in advance!